# jQuery load() not working when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery it's not working.

When the page loaded I want to show and hide some element.

It's work fine with `change()` function but not working when use `load()`

and this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        const text = '.text-type';
        const sticker = '.sticker-type';
        const image = '.image-type';
        var collection = "form div[data-form-collection='item'] select";

        $(collection).load(function(){
            var type = $(this).val();
            var row = $(this).closest("[data-form-collection='item']");

            switch (type) {
                case 'text':
                    row.find(text).show();
                    row.find(sticker).hide();
                    row.find(image).hide();
                    break;
                case 'sticker':
                    row.find(text).hide();
                    row.find(sticker).show();
                    row.find(image).hide();
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    row.find(text).hide();
                    row.find(sticker).hide();
                    row.find(image).show();
                    break;
            }
        })
})
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: try to use $(window).load

Comment: The `<select>` element does not fire a load event. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón It's not working

Comment: @Terry When the page loaded the default value of `<select>` is `'text'` so the form must show only `.text-type`

Comment: `load()` ( the way you are trying to use it )  it's deprecated . You should use `on load` instead. But, in your case, it won't work because the select element does not trigger a load event . It is already loaded when the page is loaded. So why you want to use that method ? when do you want to change the text ?

Comment: @B.Godoak You don't need to do that. At document ready, the `<select>` element should already be accessible and you don't have to wait any further (or listen to any additional events to fire, if any exists). See Marc's answer below, that is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load()` function on jQuery is for window obj or img tag, for other elements not.
When you use ready, you can assume its all loaded then you can do the same without the load function.

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const text = '.text-type';
    const sticker = '.sticker-type';
    const image = '.image-type';
    var collection = "form div[data-form-collection='item'] select";

    var type = $(collection).val();
    var row = $(collection).closest("[data-form-collection='item']");

    switch (type) {
        case 'text':
            row.find(text).show();
            row.find(sticker).hide();
            row.find(image).hide();
            break;
        case 'sticker':
            row.find(text).hide();
            row.find(sticker).show();
            row.find(image).hide();
            break;
        case 'image':
            row.find(text).hide();
            row.find(sticker).hide();
            row.find(image).show();
            break;
     }

})
```

Sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 0):

The .load() gets fired after it got loaded with `.load(url, callback)`

[JQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element

I guess you are searching for .ready()
[Jquery Ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Btw, the `$(document).ready(function () {` is fired after the page is loaded

Comment: Not necessarily: that is true for later versions of jQuery (>= v3.0), but the distinction is not drawn in older versions such as v1 and v2.